# i can't place or break blocks in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I started a new survival world and switched to creative just to build my house. When I was done, I switched back to survival. But after I switched back, I found that even when I checked and aimed and held my click, I could not break or place blocks.

I am super sad because I built a huge house and now I can do basically nothing...
How can I fix it?

I have tried switching modes and shutting my computer down, but nothing helps.

Comment: First off, FIX YOUR GRAMMAR.

Answer (score 0):

It's either two things.

1. It's a game bug and in that case email Mojang and report the problem
2. You changed you controls accidentally, check your controls and look what "Mouse 1" does

Answer (score 0):

Oh no. It can be more than two things.

1. In normal (non-bugged) Minecraft, using **Gamemode 2**, also known as **Adventure mode**, makes you unable to break and place blocks. You just can't. This is how Gamemode 2 works. Check if you switched to `/gamemode 2` instead of normal Survival mode which you can place blocks and break them normally, `/gamemode 0`.
2. As Bucky said, go to your key bind settings and check if your "Break block" key bind and "Place block" key bind is changed. Usually, you left click to break a block, and you right click to place a block. So default key bind for "Break block" should be <kbd>Button 1</kbd> and "Place block" should be <kbd>Button 2</kbd>.
3. It can also be that YOUR MOUSE IS BROKEN (well, I THINK not).
4. Bug. If it's a bug, see Bucky's answer.

Some of the concepts of this answer is from [a thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/1851503-cant-destroy-or-place-blocks) in Minecraft Forums.